# Starting new HTTPS connection (1): 1.rome.api.flipkart.com:443

Tags: python, debugging, scrapy

Hello I am running a script where we get data from certain websites and put them in a database using scrapy, the script runs well but in log text file it shows ''DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): 1.rome.api.flipkart.com:443''

what can be the real problem here, any help is appreciated, here is the code

```
import os
import sys, getopt
import time
import datetime
import pytz
import mysql.connector
import configparser
import shutil
import time
import concurrent.futures
import pandas as pd

currentdir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
parentdir = os.path.dirname(currentdir)
sys.path.append(parentdir)

from datetime import datetime
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from multiprocessing import Process
from db.db_action import DBAction
from utils import utils
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed

tz = pytz.timezone("Asia/Kolkata")

crawl_inputs = dict()
crawl_inputs["env"] = "prod"
crawl_inputs["marketplace"] = "Amazon"
crawl_inputs["site"] = "amz_kw"
crawl_inputs["db_name"] = "asian_paints"
crawl_inputs["pf_id"] = "1"
crawl_inputs["location_search"] = "0"
crawl_inputs["limit"] = ""
crawl_inputs["page"] = 1
crawl_inputs["kw_snapshot"] = 0
crawl_inputs["pdp_snapshot"] = 0
crawl_inputs["quick_search"] = 1
crawl_inputs["client_id"] = 1241
crawl_inputs["client"] = "asian_paints"
crawl_inputs["start_time"] = datetime.now(tz).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
db_action = DBAction()
actual_count = 0
result_count = 0
archived_path = "C:/archives/"
connection = None
cursor = None

# Directory Create
try:
    if not os.path.exists(archived_path):
        os.makedirs(archived_path)
    if not os.path.exists(archived_path + datetime.now(tz).strftime("%Y%m%d")+"/"+ crawl_inputs["site"]):
        os.makedirs(archived_path + datetime.now(tz).strftime("%Y%m%d")+"/"+ crawl_inputs["site"])
    if not os.path.exists("C:/var/logs/" + crawl_inputs["site"]):
        os.makedirs("C:/var/logs/" + crawl_inputs["site"])

    shutil.move("C:/var/logs/" + crawl_inputs["site"], archived_path + datetime.now(tz).strftime("%Y%m%d"), copy_function = shutil.copytree)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    print("File creation error: {0}:{1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror))

try: 
    if os.name == "nt": 
        log_path = "C:/var/logs"
        base_dir = log_path+"/"+crawl_inputs["site"]
        if not os.path.exists(base_dir):
            os.makedirs(base_dir)
    else:
        log_path = "/var/logs/"
        base_dir = log_path+"/"+crawl_inputs["site"]
        if not os.path.exists(base_dir):
            os.makedirs(base_dir)
    directories = ["output", "run_log", "webpages"]
    for directory in directories:
        if not os.path.exists(base_dir+"/"+directory):
            os.makedirs(base_dir+"/"+directory)
except OSError as oserr:
    print("OS error occurred trying to open. Aborting.. Error{0}:{1}".format(oserr.errno, oserr.strerror))
    sys.exit(1)
except IOError as ioerr:
   print("I/O Error{0}: {1}".format(ioerr.errno, ioerr.strerror))
   sys.exit(1)
except FileNotFoundError as fnfe:
    print("File not found.  Aborting.. Error: {0}:{1}".format(fnfe.errno, fnfe.strerror))
    sys.exit(1)
except Exception as e:
    print("File creation Error. Aborting.. Error: {0}:{1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror))
    sys.exit(1)

crawl_inputs = db_action.get_kw_platform_inputs(crawl_inputs)
print(f"Total Executing Inputs : {len(crawl_inputs['inputs'])}")
print("Crawl ID: {0}".format(crawl_inputs["crawl_id"]))
 
def start(input):
    pf_id = str(input["pf_id"])
    keyword =  str(input["keyword"])
    brand_id = str(input["brand_id"])
    brand_name =  str(input["brand_name"])
    keyword_id = str(input["keyword_id"])
    location_id = str(input["location_id"])
    location = str(input["location"])
    pincode = str(input["pincode"])

    location_search = str(crawl_inputs["location_search"])
    env = str(crawl_inputs["env"])
    db_name = str(crawl_inputs["db_name"])
    crawl_id = str(crawl_inputs["crawl_id"])
    site = str(crawl_inputs["site"])
    page = str(crawl_inputs["page"])

    command = 'python ' +currentdir+ '/main_kw.py --env="' +env+ '" --db_name="' +db_name+ '" --crawl_id="' +crawl_id+ '" --site="' +site+ '" --pf_id="'+pf_id+ '" --brand_id="' +brand_id+ '" --brand_name="' +brand_name+ '" --keyword_id="' +keyword_id+ '" --keyword="' +keyword+ '" --location_id="' +location_id+ '" --location="' +location+ '" --pincode="' +str(pincode)+ '" --page="' +page+ '" --location_search="' +location_search+ '"'
    print("Executing Input :{0}".format(command))
    os.system(command)
    
def runner():
    threads = []
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
        for input in crawl_inputs.get("inputs"):
            print(f"Input: {input}")
            task = executor.submit(start, input)
            threads.append(task)
            
        for task in concurrent.futures.as_completed(threads):
            print(task.result()) 
       
runner()

time.sleep(5)
crawl_inputs["finish_time"] = datetime.now(tz).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
connection = db_action.db_connection(db_name=crawl_inputs["db_name"], env=crawl_inputs["env"])
cursor = connection.cursor()
try:
    cursor.execute("update `amazon_crawl_kw` set `status` = 0 where `crawl_id` != " +str(crawl_inputs["crawl_id"])+ ";")
    cursor.execute("select count(kw_crawl_data_id) as product_count from `amazon_crawl_kw` where status = 1 and  pf_id = "+str(crawl_inputs["pf_id"])+ " and crawl_id=" +str(crawl_inputs["crawl_id"])+ ";")
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    print("row value: "+ str(row))
    result_count = row["product_count"]
    print("Crawled row count : " + str(result_count))
    
    try:
        sql2 = 'UPDATE rb_crawl SET status=1, end_time = "' +str(crawl_inputs["finish_time"])+ '" ,no_of_sku_parsed='+ str(result_count)+ ' WHERE crawl_id=' + str(crawl_inputs["crawl_id"])
        cursor.execute(sql2)
    except Exception as e:
        print("The following exception occured while updating : "+ str(e))
    sql3 = 'UPDATE rb_platform SET kw_crawl_data_date = "'+ str(crawl_inputs["start_time"]) + '", kw_crawl_data_id = ' +str(crawl_inputs["crawl_id"])+ ' WHERE pf_id = ' + str(crawl_inputs["pf_id"])
    cursor.execute(sql3)
    connection.commit()
    connection.close()
    print("Updated rb_platform successfully")
except Exception as e:
    print("Updating crawl id failed with exception as :" + str(e))

# try:
#     items_count = result_count
#     subject = crawl_inputs["site"] +" crawling completed"
#     body = "Hi Team,<br><br>" +crawl_inputs["site"]+ " crawling successfully completed for the plateform " +crawl_inputs["marketplace"]+ "...<br>Platform Id: " +str(crawl_inputs["pf_id"])+ "<br>Crawl Id: " +str(crawl_inputs["crawl_id"])+ "<br>Total crawled items: " +str(items_count)+ " <br>Total Actual Items: " + str(actual_count) +" <br>Please QC the data value..<br><br>Thanks<br>Trailytics Team"
#     utils.send_mail("no-reply@trailytics.com", "vijay.kothawar@trailytics.com;ashish.rawat@trailytics.com;anirudh.varshney@trailytics.com;ashutosh.shukla@trailytics.com", subject, body)
#     print("Crawling process has been completed")
# except Exception as e:
#     print("Mail Sending error:" + str(e))
print("Finish")
```

Comment: The full logs or at least the several items surrounding the one you are asking about would help.  But from what I can tell it is simply a matter of an improperly formed url being requested. I am not going to lie though your code looks like some of my nightmares

Comment: Having a traceback here would certainly help in finding the cause of the issue, so please add that. Also, if you could refactor your code a little so that it becomes more readable for humans, this would most certainly be very helpful.